# Dimension of intersection of two nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S and T be two nonzero linear mappings from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Prove that $dim(N(S)\cap N(T))\geq n-2$

Note that $N(S)$ stands for nullity of S.

I do not have idea how the intersection of nullspace will be.
I got tried to link it with the formula 
$$dim(U+V)=dim(U)+dim(V)-dim(U\cap V)$$
But I still do not have idea how the $N(S)+N(T)$ will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that by the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of the nullspace of any linear functional from $\Bbb R^n$ to $R$ is $n-1$. Thus $N(S) = n-1 = N(T)$. From your dimension counting, we have that

$$\dim(N(S)\cap N(T)) = \dim(N(S))+\dim(N(T))-\dim(N(S)+N(T)).$$

With our above observation, this becomes

$$\dim(N(S)\cap N(T)) = 2n-2-\dim(N(S)+N(T)).$$

Now note that $\dim(N(S)+N(T)) \le n$ since they are *subspaces* of $\Bbb R^n$. Do you see how this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Define the mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $\phi(x) = (Sx, Tx)$. Notice that $x \in \ker S \cap \ker T$ **iff** $x \in \ker \phi$.

We have $n = \dim {\cal R} \phi + \dim \ker \phi$, and since $\dim {\cal R} \phi \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $n \le 2 + \dim \ker \phi$ which is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ranges of $S$ and $T$ are $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\dim(R(S)) \leq 1$ and $\dim(R(T)) \leq 1$.

By dimension theorem, $n = \dim(R(S)) + \dim(N(S))$ and therefore 
$$\dim(N(S)) \geq n - 1$$

Similarly, 
$$\dim(N(T)) \geq n - 1$$

Certainly, we have from $N(S) + N(T) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\dim(N(S) + N(T)) \leq n$$

Finally, as you have already spotted
$$\dim(N(S) \cap N(T)) = \dim(N(S)) + \dim(N(T)) - \dim(N(S)+N(T))$$
$$\dim(N(S) \cap N(T)) \geq (n - 1) + (n - 1) - n = n - 2$$

Note that to get this inequality the linear operators $S$ and $T$ are non-zero are indeed redundant.

Comment: should be intersection not union.

Comment: @AlanWang: Thanks for your reminder. I always mistype cap as cup.